# What is the bar symbol over a complex scalar in the expression $\overline{\lambda}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, notation, definition

I have the following problem from section 1.4 (Vector Spaces) of Peter Peterson's [Linear Algebra](http://www.calpoly.edu/%7Ejborzell/Courses/Year%2010-11/Fall%202010/Petersen-Linear_Algebra-Math_306.pdf) textbook. I am having trouble with the way multiplication is defined on the given vector space, $\bf{V}^{*}$.

> 6.Let $\mathbf{V}$ be a complex vector space i.e., a vector space were the scalars are $\mathbb{C}$.
>
> Define $\mathbf{V}^{*}$ as the complex vector space whose additive structure is that of $\mathbf{V}$ but where complex scalar multiplication is given by
> $$\lambda\cdot x=\overline{\lambda}x.$$
> Show that $\mathbf{V}^{*}$ is a complex vector space.

Does the bar over $\lambda$ on the right-hand side mean anything? Does it have something to do with complex numbers?

Thank you, and I apologize for the trivial question. From the definition, I should be able to easily show that it is a vector space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $\lambda$ is a scalar, hence a real, or in the case here, a complex number, so it makes sense to talk about $\overline{\lambda}$, the complex conjugate. As a sidenote, do note that if $\bf V$ is a real vector space, then ${\bf V}^\ast = {\bf V}$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! 
To show that ${\bf V}^\ast = {\bf V}$, should I simply show that each is a subspace of the other? What is the definition of two sub-spaces being equal?

Comment: No. Recall that a vector space is a $4$-uple $({\bf V}, \Bbb F,  + ,\cdot)$, and we abuse notation and call everything $\bf V$. More exactly, we have ${\bf V} = ({\bf V}, \Bbb R, +, \cdot)$ and ${\bf V}^\ast = ({\bf V},\Bbb R, + , \ast)$ in the real case, and $\cdot = \ast$, so they're equal.

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It denotes complex conjugation ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate)). Given a complex number $\lambda=a+ib$, we define its complex conjugate to be
$$\overline{\lambda}:=a-ib$$